# Pandas:How to convert date format %Y-%M-%D into %Y%M%D?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, format-conversion

I have a dataframe, which can be shown as follows:

**Input**

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.DataFrame({'time':['2018-07-04','2018-04-03',]})
print('df\n',df)
```

**Output**

```
         time
0  2018-07-04
1  2018-04-03
```

**Expected**

```
     time
0  20180704
1  20180403
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
print (df)
       time
0  20180704
1  20180403
```

Solution with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['time'] = df['time'].str.replace('-','')
print (df)
       time
0  20180704
1  20180403
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['time'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('-',''))
```

this should to the trick since your current values are just strings.